# Concatenate multiple rows in single rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation

How can I concatenate all the rows in single rows when I fire SELECT query?

[image]

I want O/P like

101 abc CA USA 102 xyz PH UK 103 pqr WDC EU

Any help kindly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: yipes... why?  this will not scale at all.

Answer (score 12):

Use conbination of `group_concat` and `concat` functions

```
 SELECT group_concat( concat( id, " ",name," ",city," ",state," " ) SEPARATOR ' ')
 FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 11):

You'll need [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) mysql functions and the query should look like this:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( id, ' ', name, ' ', city, ' ', state) SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM students
GROUP BY (1)
```

Or you can use [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead:

```sql
CONCAT_WS(' ', id, name, city, state)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the links to GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT_WS are broken :-/