# How to set goup_concat separater in sql to be a column field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have a table with a column of artist and another of symbol and would like to join them into one cell. When joining I get the following error when I try this

```
SELECT LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID, group_concat( ARTIST
SEPARATOR SYMBOL )
FROM artist_view
GROUP BY LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID
```

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SYMBOL) FROM artist_view group by LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID LIMIT

How do I get the separater to be my SYMBOL field

## EDIT: What worked for me

This is what eventually worked for me. I found the answer here:

[Concatenate multiple rows in single rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116501/concatenate-multiple-rows-in-single-rows-in-mysql)

```
SELECT 
  LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID,
  group_concat( concat( ARTIST, " ",SYMBOL," " ) SEPARATOR '' )
FROM artist_view
GROUP BY LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, the `SEPARATOR` must be a string literal, you can't put a column or an expression. Quoted from the [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> use SEPARATOR followed by **the string literal value** that should be
>   inserted between group values.

Use a string literal as a separator instead.

Comment: So my best bet would be to join my artist column to symbol with a separater of a space and then join all those rows together?

Comment: @Mark - Yes, since the `SYMBOL` is coming from the other table, you can use `CONCAT` and join the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to separate `ARTIST,SYMBOL,SEPARATOR` combinations within each `LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID` but this should get you started:

```
select LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID,group_concat(grouped)
from
(
select LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID,ARTIST,`SEPARATOR`,`SYMBOL`,
concat(ARTIST,`SEPARATOR`,SYMBOL) as grouped
from artist_view av
) t
group by LOOK_UP_TO_CAT_ID;
```